# Replace Items in List with Random Items from Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list of items that may repeat multiple times. Let us say for example

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

I also have a dictionary of lists that defines multiple values for each key. Suppose:

```
dict = {'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4], 'c':[5, 6], 'd':[7, 8]}
```

I want to be able to:

1. randomly select a value from the dictionary where the key is equal to the value in the original list, and
2. have this value be randomly selected at **each key occurrence** in the list.

I attempted to use `Pandas` to create a `DataFrame` from my list and leverage `pd.Series.map()` to randomly map my dictionary like in the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list, index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], columns = ['Letters'])
df['Random_Values'] = df['Letters'].map({k:random.choice(v) for k,v in dict.items()})
```

Output:

```
         Letters      Random_Values
    0       a              1
    1       b              3
    2       c              5
    3       d              7
    4       b              3
    5       a              1
    6       c              5
    7       a              1
```

This code is successful in randomly selecting a value where the key matches, but it currently randomly selects the same value for every key (i.e., all instances of 'a' will always be 1 or 2, not a mixture).

How can I alter this code to randomly select the values each time the key is matched? Any advice appreciate, Pandas not essential -- if you have a better way with just lists I want to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the built-in `random.choice` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import random
>>>
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a']
>>> my_dict = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4], 'c':[5,6], 'd':[7,8]}
>>>
>>> [(key, random.choice(my_dict[key])) for key in my_list]
[('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 6), ('d', 8), ('b', 4), ('a', 1), ('c', 6), ('a', 1)]
```

As a side note, don't use builtins such as `list` and `dict` as your variable names as they will shadow the builtins.